# Simple Facebook Connect Demo in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, facebook

Does anyone have a simple and successful demo implementation of facebook connect in an asp.net application. I am developing an asp.net web application and want facebook connect to be the primary method for logging in.

Comment: [http://petersirka.sk/development/asp-mvc-asp-net-facebook-login-connect/](http://petersirka.sk/development/asp-mvc-asp-net-facebook-login-connect/) Translated:
[http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=sk&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpetersirka.sk%2Fdevelopment%2Fasp-mvc-asp-net-facebook-login-connect%2F](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=sk&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://petersirka.sk/development/asp-mvc-asp-net-facebook-login-connect/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having troubles as well, but found that [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323019/facebook-connect-and-asp-net) got me on the right track as far as the server side stuff is concerned

However, First you have to get the facebook connect button working from here [Facebook Wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Logging_In_And_Connecting)

Then detect if they are logged in or not and redirect them appropriately to a welcome page.
[Detect login via Javascript](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Detecting_Connect_Status)

Most other actions can be done via serverside with the Facebook ToolKit. (eg get their information, friends, etc..)

The last thing I think I should mention is logging the user out, so take a look at this. [Facebook Wiki: Logout](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Logging_Out_And_Disconnecting)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

As I see, all the above examples and links are really outdated. The new Facebook Graph API makes the whole process a lot easier, without the need for any other components:

http://area72.ro/general-it/how-to-login-via-facebook-in-asp-net.html

Answer (score 0):

try to use the toolkit called [Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/FacebookToolkit)

you have in [Steve](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/) Blog a [post about it](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Facebook%20application%20development%20in%20ASP.NET&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), and you even download he's [Starter Kit](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/files/FacebookApp2008v2.0.vsi) so you can view all the code :)

Hope it helps

Comment: Facebook Connect != Facebook App. Connect is like OpenID

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for ASP.NET resources.  The Facebook Connect page provides some good information as well as the source to a sample implementation using PHP.  Hopefully you can pull some good information from the PHP code.

http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php  Check out the links on the right side.

The provided demo can be accessed here... http://www.somethingtoputhere.com/therunaround/