# How to authenticate C# web application with facebook users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to authenticate my application with facebook users.
If any user wants to login into my application He/she first gets redirected to facebook login page & add  username and password, It then redirects back to my application with success/failure message.

How to achieve this in C# application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this SO: [Simple Facebook Connect Demo in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444846/simple-facebook-connect-demo-in-asp-net)

And at [New Facebook Connect in C#](http://www.atlasbay.com/2010/04/21/new-facebook-connect-in-csharp/)

Comment: Hello @CD do you have sample code. C# web application to redirect to facebook login page and get back to our web application...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ ?