# Facebook Connect Integration with a site using ASP.NET Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook

Are there any best practices or examples of how to best integrate Facebook connect with an  existing ASP.NET Application using the Membership provider (or something similar).  I'm sure I can get something going, but, it would be great if there was some information and best practices on this to mitigate any security concerns.  Currently I can have a user 'connect' and grab their information, but, I would like to handle them as securely as possible and as similarly as possible to the existing users.  Particularly, I would like them to have an entry in the 'users' table.

It would be extra helpful for any information relating to ASP.NET MVC.

Some useful links i have found to date:

- http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=45825
- [Facebook Connect and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323019/facebook-connect-and-asp-net)

Comment: http://amirrajan.net/Blog/asp-mvc-and-facebook-single-sign-on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into RPXNow:
https://rpxnow.com/

It'll allow you to integrate your app with a whole range of OpenId providers, and i believe with Facebook amongst them, with a nice tidy API.
If you only want facebook as a provider, you may want to look elsewhere however

Answer (score 3):

https://rpxnow.com/ has changed its name to "Janrain" and is commercialized. It would be nice to know the technology behind it in order to create a solution of your own.

Does anyone know an open source, free solution like "Janrain"? Or a good tutorial, suitable for ASP.NET MVC 2?