# Has anyone written or used a Asp.NET membership provider that integrates with Facebook Connect?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, facebook

I'm looking to allow Facebook Connect logins on my site, but still want to capture some user information and store it in the Profile object.  Would also like to allow standard login/pass authentication, with an option to link it to your Facebook account. Much like the way many sites handle Facebook Connect...

I'm wondering if someone has something pre-written (aside from the Facebook Toolkit on CodePlex) specifically for Asp.NET Membership integration with Facebook Connect.

Answer (score 4):

Related questions on StackOverflow:

- [Facebook Connect Integration with a site using ASP.NET Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645289/facebook-connect-integration-with-a-site-using-asp-net-membership-provider-)
- [Facebook Connect and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323019/facebook-connect-and-asp-net)

An open source provider:

- http://fbmembership.codeplex.com/