# Facebook connect

Tags: facebook

I have followed  [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323019/facebook-connect-and-asp-net). I don't want him to be autologgedin if he has logged into facebook, only if he logged into my website. Is there a way to distinguise between the cookie/session if it is set at facebooks own site, or my own? Right now it returns a user if he just logged into facebook, even if he has never logged into my website?

Answer (score 1):

This is not what should be happening.

If a facebook user visits your site, they should not be logged in until they click the connect button.

Once they have 'connected', you can auto-login on page reload, but not before.

Otherwise, any site could add facebook connect scripts and secretly connect to a users facebook account without their knowing.

Comment: Only if they've added your application, however.