# Making Facebook Connect work with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am trying to integrate my ASP.Net MVC site with Facebook Connect.

For some odd reason after the login popup loads and connets, `HttpContxt.Current.Requet.Cookies[Session_Key_Cookie_Name]` still returns NULL!

What could be the possible reason?

Thanks

P.S

I also noticed that although I've set localhost/xd_receiver in the Site.Master FB.init call, xd_receiverController.cs doesn't get called (Set a breakpoint in it)

( I followed all those posts/articles when buiding my site:
http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-retrieve-user-data-from-facebook-connect-in-aspnet/ ,
[Facebook Connect and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323019/facebook-connect-and-asp-net),
http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=45825,
http://my6solutions.com/post/2009/04/05/Integration-of-Facebook-Connect-on-ASP-NET-MVC.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution, hopefully this will save people the days I have burned trying to use ASP.Net and Facebook Connect.

The issue is simple:

The connect url property in your facebook application settings page MUST be your domain name AND the xd_receiver path in the FB.init is the **relative** path from the page your connect button is on!

otherways it wont save the session cookie in the right place.

Goodluck

Comment: I'm working on something very similar to this right now.  Would you mind posting example values here?