# How can I update MessageStatus of my account in Facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I have create a web application that only contains a textbox in which I can type a text in and  press the button to send this text to my status.

I used the follwing link
[Facebook Connect and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323019/facebook-connect-and-asp-net)

I have created an application on my facebook profile and I set the API Key & secret key 
but I found that `SessionKey=Null` & `UserID=0` and I cannot solve this problem.

All ideas are welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still trying to use the Facebook Toolkit that is mentioned in that SO post you referenced or not, but I would highly recommend using the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/). I had multiple connection problems with other libraries and this was the only one that worked for me. This uses the new Facebook Graph API which is much simpler and is the way Facebook is moving.

Comment: Thanks Kyle for your reply                                         In this toolkit I found that I must run app under IIS not under VS but how can I test it under VS as I cannot solve problem http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%20Sample&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. You can just build the src for whatever framework you need and include it in any visual studio project.