# Login on site with other site creadentials in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, authentication, credentials

I have developed asp.net MVC social networking site. I do not want to keep credentials at my database. Its user choice like stackoverflow (this forum). When we saying login the there should be option that to login with google/yahoo/facebook credentials,  if user has account over there. What I have to do? is there any webservice provided by sites (google/yahoo/facebook) or what is remedy over this ? this topic in totally new for me . I expecting help from you gems..

Comment: Are you talking about a CAS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service) ?

Comment: As far I can suggestion you logically , following SO's approach for multiple login is quite cool. Stack Over Flow has its own api. So i think you can get idea from there by playing with the code. I havent applied such things .. but its like a bow in dark. SO guru will definitely help you out.

Comment: @Amit Ranjan : No dear , its not a bow in dark. It is time saver now a days. and if SO have such functionality so it should be some contract over there , agree with API's but it should be there . Otherwise its kind of hacking the servers...isn't it ?..anyway I want just solution about this ....

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like OpenId would work for you ([click](http://www.openid.co.uk/), and [more](http://openid.net/)).

[Library's to use in your apps.](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [OpenID](http://openid.net/). [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) is implementation for .NET.

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook you want to use [Facebook Connect](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=730). There is an [implementation for .net on codeplex](http://fbconnectauth.codeplex.com/) that you may want to have a look at. You may also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323019/facebook-connect-and-asp-net).

Google uses OpenId. You can use [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) to connect to google (and any other OpenId provider, such as [Yahoo](http://openid.yahoo.com/) and twitter).

If you want to connect with Microsoft's LiveId, you may want to read [this tutorial](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/48857836-0c72-4efb-9d29-fbcb8e17ef3a/integrate-windows-live-id.aspx).

**EDIT**

There is also the option of using [JanRain](http://www.janrain.com/), a single provider that consolidates a large number of login providers. But note that JanRain is only free up to 1000 users.

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions that enable authentication and features (like status updates, friends etc) from all mentioned sites, one of them is RPX from JanRain. I've experience with RPX personally and it's a great product, however, it will cost you money. They charge you per registered user etc.. I do not know of an open source solution that can compete with RPX.

If you are not interested in paying for a product you can always implement support for the mentioned sites yourself. All of them provide open API's and examples for how to do this. For Facebook it's very easy to implement Facebook Connect. Google and Yahoo both support Open ID and there are plenty of open source resources available for .NET (like http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/).

Good luck with your community!

Comment: Yes, JanRain is easy to implement, but in my opinion it is ridiculously expensive. When you reach a thousand users it will start costing you 0.5$ per additional user. Ouch.

Comment: If it's expensive or not depends on the number of users you have/expect. If you run a reasonable small site <100.000 users and you really need/want most of the functionality that RPX offer, you will save money using RPX.