# Session Key Facebookservice status.set question

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

My question is simple. I just want to post a status update from my desktop application. The app contains a textbox and a button... on button click, I would like to set the textbox.text to facebook based on the user access Token.
I found 1 tutorial that says all you need to use is:

```
FacebookService1.ApplicationKey = apiKey
FacebookService1.Secret = appsecret '<-- but secret is not available
```

Can anyone correct/post code that will update a status through a desktop app after I already of the AccessToken from the user "allow"ing my app?

```
Imports Facebook
Imports Facebook.Winforms

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        Dim accessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

        FacebookService1.ApplicationKey = apiKey
        FacebookService1.SessionKey = apiKey + accessToken
        FacebookService1.ConnectToFacebook()

        FacebookService1.Status.Set(TextBox1.Text.Trim())

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The app secret for your specific app is available from http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php .

> ```
> App ID
> 111111111111111111 
> API Key
> 2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a 
> App Secret
> 3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b3b
> ```

The session key will change every time you log in. I don't know the specific code in C# but in javascript you get it from FB.getSession(). The most general approach would be to read the cookie.

**BTW: There are a few other questions in SO that I just found dealing with the same. For example,**

```
API api = new API();
api.ApplicationKey = Utility.ApiKey();
api.SessionKey = Utility.SessionKey();
api.Secret = Utility.SecretKey();
api.uid = Utility.GetUserID();
```

which I got from [Facebook Connect and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323019/facebook-connect-and-asp-net)

You can read also http://buruonbrails.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-deal-with-facebook-api-infamous.html

Comment: okay, I've got that info already. What is the session key? is it the same as the access token? or a combination of a few?