# Login to website using Facebook account

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, single-sign-on, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I want to implement SSO in our current website so that we can login to that website using a Facebook account. Can you please provide the steps which I need to follow to implement it?

Answer (score 5):

Mixu had meticulously explained single sign-on in his 3 paged blog:

1) http://blog.mixu.net/2010/12/27/implementing-facebook-login-single-sign-on-part-1/

2) http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/03/implementing-facebook-login-part-2/

3) http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/09/implementing-facebook-login-part-3/

**UPDATE**

SSO is simply logging a user with facebook and maintaining a site-wide session on your server and cookie on user's machine. This session shall remain valid for all pages on your website. You can use this codeplex example in C# to get you going on the right track: http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

Also see this answer (in C#) for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/369691/842837

Comment: steps they have shown in php...my application is in c#. do u have any sample application in which the integration is been done in c#. I have to do a demo on Monday so i m screwed big time.

Comment: @AkanshaGulati I have updated answer. Please go through it again.

Comment: If it answers your question, consider upvoting and marking it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can implement this. These architectures are explained in the Facebook developer page.

The simplest way is to implement it using javascript sdk. Here is a link on [how to login using Facebook account](http://a4academics.com/blog/381-login-using-facebook-account-fbconnect).

Answer (score 1):

We can authenticate user from server side as well as client side.. if you are looking for a javascript solution then please refer below mentioned method.

- Browse this link
  https://developers.facebook.com

  - Click on apps tab. >> It will promt you for login.
  - Once you are logged in >> you can create an new app in your account.
  - Click on settings tab(from left pannel)>> then click on "advanced" tab on the right window.
  - under  "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" >> enter proper  url  (for testing you can enter your localhost url also, something like localhost.com:98 etc)
    if you are using iis you can configure the port number there.
  - if required you will have to put this url in your host file as well.
  - from the dashboard tab you can get the appid and secrect key for the newly created app.(we will need this in later stage).

Answer (score -1):

SSO is simply logging a user with facebook and maintaining a site-wide session on your server and cookie on user's machine. This session shall remain valid for all pages on your website. You can use this codeplex example in C# to get you going on the right track: http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include all the necessary details in your answer rather than linking to a resource outside the site.