# Facebook login authorisation for my website

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am building a website in PHP that has a log in section. For this I have a table in a MySQL database that stores 64bit hashed passwords and the users details. When a user enters their email and password the site hashes the password and compares it with the stored hash. To set up an account the user must register.

I want to integrate Facebook log in so users don't have to go through registration and can just log in to the password protected section of my site using their Facebook account. Which incidentally is exactly how I logged into stackoverflow just now. I have been researching this but can't find any up to date tutorials on how to do this.

Can some one please enlighten me as to how I can integrate Facebook log in to authenticate users to the protected part of my website?

Does my database need to provide a table for Facebook registered users? Do I enter facebook users details into my database at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into JanRain if you don't want to write something from scratch.  http://janrain.com/products/engage/social-login/

They provide free (for less than 2500 users) single signon that integrates with all major services like Twitter, FB, Google, Yahoo, etc.  very straightforward to implement as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can start through the developer page of Facebook itself. See the [Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/)

Comment: I have looked though loads of this but find it all a bit confusing. I was hoping I could find a tutorial that explains exactly how to do this step by step. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I think the links under the General section may be useful. For instance, the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/ and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/. And this may be more concrete for you: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Comment: My site is a php site should I be using the php sdk rather than the javascript one

Comment: Then this would work for you: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

Answer (score 0):

Check this link.
[Login to website using Facebook account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665928/login-to-website-using-facebook-account/22132652#22132652)

We can handle this from server side as well as client side. in the above mentioned link you will find the solution to do this using javascript.

Some steps

- Browse this link https://developers.facebook.com
- Click on apps tab. >> It will promt you for login.
- Once you are logged in >>
  you can create an new app in your account.
- Click on settings
  tab(from left pannel) >> then click on "advanced" tab on the right
  window.
- Under "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" >> enter proper url
  (for testing you can enter your    -localhost url also, something
  like localhost.com:98 etc) if you are using iis you can configure the
  port number there.    -if required you will have to put this url in
  your host file as well.
- From the dashboard tab you can get the app id and secrect key for the newly created app.(we will need this in
  later stage).